# Right to left in android application

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left

I want to make the first word from right to left.

IF i click on the button to show me the first word its work but its show me on the left in need it in the right

[image: img]

Code

```
String letter = "";
boolean isFound = false;
for (int i = 0; i < mWordInfo.Word.length(); i++) {
    letter = mWordInfo.Word.substring(i,i + 1);
    isFound = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < mLetters.size(); j++) {
        if (!mLetters.get(j).isButton
                && !mLetters.get(j).isTargetLetter) {
            if (mLetters.get(j).Letter.equals(letter)) {
                mLetters.get(j).isTargetLetter = true;
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (isFound)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: These boxes in the top row look like separate text fields. If that's so, maybe your layout is mirrored (turns right-to-left) when you run the app. You can try to check this in Android Studio preview.

Comment: remove android:supportsRtl from manifest

Comment: @ReZa there are many little features, like action bar behavior and accessibility that will work better if Android correctly understands that the app layout is right-to-left

Comment: @AlexCohn you are right . but i think he's intention is only rtl app and he designed the layout only for rtl . so when  running the app , android also tries to make layout rtl and that makes this result .